# Starting airplay from command line, to send output of 'Say' Mac OS X command to airplay

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, audio, airplay

Ok, Sunday question :) Trying to make a little joke...

1) if you open a terminal, and type "say -a ?", Mac OS X will give you the list of devices it can send spoken words to.  On mine, it says:

```
39 AirPlay
47 Built-in Output
```

2) I have a Denon airplay-ready received in my living room and I'm trying to send spoken words to my wife downstairs... I can send music without any problem using iTunes so, from an infrastructure standpoint, I'm all set.

3) I want my computer to say (out of the blue) "Honey, why don't you bring me a cup of coffee".  I can make it say that locally on my internal laptop speakers, but I can't seem to send that to device 39 successfully.

I am suspecting that there are a few other things that need to be setup before it works, i.e. setting up airplay output to "denon", maybe opening a channel and reserving it.  I don't know.

Has anyone played with this?  Is there a way to setup airplay from the command line?  That would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `say -a AirPlay "Honey, why don't you bring me a cup of coffee"` seems to work for me better than using the numbers. You could play with the rate (-r) and voice (-v) to get the effect you want.

Comment: Great idea but if you're doing all that ***just*** for a cup of coffee, you're wasting you time! ;-)